# WCF receiving empty int

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, wcf

For some reason my wcf service is not receiving the data from my POST correctly.

It gives me this error:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Int32. The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'.'

The ajax request looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "ShopService.svc/Product",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: 1 }),
        success: function (data) {
            returndata = data;
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

And the service code is like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Product", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Product GetProduct(int id)
    {
        Product selectedProduct = db.Products.Find(id);

        return selectedProduct;
    }
```

I don't know what's going wrong here, why is the server seeing the id as empty string?

Comment: can you post a sample data for the json object that you receive in the service?

Comment: @Y.Ecarri I'm not receiving anything in the service, the error happens before I get anything into there.

Comment: As far as I know, you should receive strings and then parse the strings as shown here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-sec

Comment: @Y.Ecarri but what if I want to do it without adding my id to my link?

Comment: Ok, I found an answer. Posted it up below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright guys, I figured it out after dealing with some more complex objects.

I need to set the BodyStyle attribute of my WebInvoke to WrappedRequest to get the correct deserializing going.

So now my service function looks like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,  UriTemplate = "/Products", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Product GetProduct(string id)
    {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(id);

        Product selectedProduct = db.Products.Find(ID);

        return selectedProduct;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify datatype and type as:

```
 $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "ShopService.svc/Product",
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: 1 }),
             type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            returndata = data;
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have to pass an `id` then try passing it with the URL.

`var id = 1;
url: "ShopService.svc/Product/" + id;`

Comment: This does not work, as it changes the URL I gave up in the template! It cannot find the function this way.

Comment: Try changing the `UriTemplate` as: `[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Product/{id}", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]`

Comment: I'm just scared that when I get to the more complex stuff, this will happen too, but that works for now.

Comment: Well, that is the ideal way if you have a single parameter like an id. And if that solves your issue then please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the integer 1 directly and remove content-type instead of sending a json object with a field id and value 1, as you service expects an integer not an object

```
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "ShopService.svc/Product",
        async: false,
        data: 1,
        success: function (data) {
            returndata = data;
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This does not work, my service says id is 0 every time.

Comment: @Firenter well first this solved your type conversion problem which is good, now you have to make sure that you are sending a non-zero value. If you are sure that its different from 0, try changing the type of parameter 'id' from 'int' to 'object' in your service method and then check the value.